# Finding a pattern from a combination of String, Numerical Digit and special character in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like below.

```
COURSE_ID
INC-AAB-WW-105614
INC-AAB-DE-234567
INC-AAB-NL-WFT-PA-BS-123489
INC-AAB-NL-WFT-PA-SI-145678-SYS-2020
EXI-WDFT-145678
```

From here I need to fetch only

- INC part
- AAB part
- WW/DE/NL/AU/NW(like this) where these are country code and
- 6 digit coursecode  105614/234567/123489.

For rest which are not starting with INC-AAB will be same as it is. Country codes are available in another look up table. So the final dataframe will look like this.

```
COURSE_ID
INC-AAB-WW-105614
INC-AAB-DE-234567
INC-AAB-NL-123489
INC-AAB-NL-145678
EXI-WDFT-145678
```

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Answer (score 2):

pandas isn't my forte, but maybe something use regular epxressions in a replace function?

```
df['COURSE_ID'] = df['COURSE_ID'].str.replace(r'^(INC-AAB-[A-Z]+).*?(-\d{6})\b.*$', r'\1\2')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           COURSE_ID
0  INC-AAB-WW-105614
1  INC-AAB-DE-234567
2  INC-AAB-NL-123489
3  INC-AAB-NL-145678
4    EXI-WDFT-145678
```

---

The idea behind `^(INC-AAB-[A-Z]+).*?(-\d{6})\b.*$` is:

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(INC-AAB-[A-Z]+)` - A 1st capture group holding your desired start of "INC-AAB-" and any 1+ uppercase characters (alpha).
- `.*?` - A lazy match of 0+ characters upto;
- `(-\d{6})` - A 2nd capture group holding your desired pattern of a hyphen and 6 digits upto;
- `\b.*` - A word boundary and 0+ (greedy) characters.
- `$` - End line anchor.

We can than concatenate all the capture groups to get your desired result:

```
\1\2
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pCv0Lk/1)

Comment: Would be great if you could add an explanation of your regex

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
df['COURSE_ID'] = df['COURSE_ID'].str.replace(r'^(INC-AAB-[A-Z]+-)(?:[A-Z]+-)*(\d+).*', r'\1\2')
```

- `^(INC-AAB-[A-Z]+-)` matches a substring `INC-AAB-` at the beginning of
  the string followed by a country code and a hyphen. Then the matched
  substring is captured in Group 1 (referred by `\1`).
- `(?:[A-Z]+-)*` matches the optional country codes which are discarded.
- `(\d+)` matches the course code which is captured in Group 2 (`\2`).
- `.*` matches the remaining fragment which is discarded.

Output:

```
           COURSE_ID
0  INC-AAB-WW-105614
1  INC-AAB-DE-234567
2  INC-AAB-NL-123489
3  INC-AAB-NL-145678
4    EXI-WDFT-145678
```